# Sage Pay Protocol Upgrading in Opencart

Tags: opencart, opayo

I have been told by Sage Pay that we need to upgrade the protocol used by OpenCart to version 3 so that we can make use of Credit Card Surcharges. I can see that my SagePay in opencart is using protocol 2.23, but I have zero idea of how to upgrade it. Sagepay have sent me a pdf explaining who the integration works but it doesn't touch on updating in a opencart environment.

The module I am using for sagepay is the one that comes with opencart 1.5.5.1

Would someone be kind to help me out?

Thank you
Andy

Comment: Would anyone be kind enough to help with this as Im struggling with it. I cant even find the intergration kits on Sagepays Website :(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-document/form-integration

Java and .net kits shown on this page.